# Remove '-' from column SUM

Tags: sql

Group,
I need to remove the '-' from any negative numbers in a column for certain record numbers.  However the Sum needs to * by .01 to get the correct format.  I tried using replace but it is getting thrown off by the *.01  Below is my syntax.

```
CASE WHEN SUM(ExtPrice) *.01 < 0 AND RecordNum BETWEEN 4000 AND 5999 
        THEN REPLACE(SUM(ExtPrice) *.01,'-','')
     ELSE SUM(ExtPrice) *.01 
END AS Totals
```

For example `SUM(ExtPrice) *.01`  in one column gives me -5051.32 but when I use the above case statement I get 5050 another example -312.67 and I get 310 using the case. Any suggestions or better ways to do this are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you specify what language or product you're using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the ABS function to get the positive value of a number. For example:

```
ABS(-123.445) /* this equals 123.445 */
```

So you can replace your CASE statement with:

```
CASE WHEN SUM(ExtPrice) < 0 AND RecordNum BETWEEN 4000 AND 5999         
         THEN ABS(SUM(ExtPrice) *.01)     
     ELSE SUM(ExtPrice) *.01 
END AS Totals
```

Comment: Just CASE WHEN SUM(ExtPrice) < 0 to start seems better -- why multiply by .01 there, that doesn't change the sign.

Comment: @Alex - Good observation, I had copied the code down as it was.